# Structured bindings in Python

Tags: python, c++

C++17 introduced the new structured bindings syntax:

```cpp
std::pair<int, int> p = {1, 2};
auto [a, b] = p;
```

Is there something similar in python3? I was thinking of using the "splat" operator to bind class variables to a list, which can be unpacked and assigned to multiple variables like such:

```py
class pair:
    def __init__(self, first, second):
        self.first = first
        self.second = second
...

p = pair(1, 2)
a, b = *p
```

Is this possible? And if so, how would I go by implementing this to work for my own classes?

A tuple in Python works as a simple solution to this problem. However, built in types don't give much flexibility in implementing other class methods.

Comment: Are you looking for a tuple? `p = (1, 2)` `a, b = p`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use `__iter__` method since iterators can be unpacked too:

```py
class pair:
    def __init__(self, first, second):
        self.first = first
        self.second = second
    def __iter__(self):
        # Use tuple's iterator since it is the closest to our use case.
        return iter((self.first, self.second))

p = pair(1, 2)
a, b = p
print(a, b) # Prints 1 2
```

Comment: `a, b = *p` still doesn't work with that.

Comment: `yield self.first` `yield self.second` might be a good alternative.

Answer (score 2):

You can use tuples and tuple unpacking (see the bottom of [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) section in the Python documentation):

```py
p = (1, 2)
a, b = p
print(a, b) # Prints 1 2
```

Comment: The problem with using built in types is that I can't implement other class methods, but thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative with [dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html):

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, astuple

@dataclass
class pair:
    first: int
    second: int

p = pair(1, 2)
a, b = astuple(p)
print(a, b)
```

Output ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYyxCsMwDER3fYVGG7y0XUqg0F9REocaEltI6tCvdxy3pDcc3ONx/LFXybc7S62LlA1nMppWUo2KaeMi9kcBSe3NawR4nhB6I1OSAbBlSaI2YMrWp8ap5Pm7gfHRTXcJePVAAcdGfq@OPbA0zx3c17oD)):

```
1 2
```

Comment: I would still be inclined to add `def __iter__(self): return iter(astuple(self))` to remove the need for `astuple` call in user code